# How can I use HashiCorp Vault Agent with multiple approles

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I'm using Hashicorp Vault to store secrets.  I have some servers that need to pull secrets from 2 different backends.  I have a role set up for each backend, with corresponding approle credentials.  I generally use Vault Agent to maintain tokens, but I can't find a way to set up auto-auth with 2 sets of approle credentials.  The Vault Agent config doesn't allow 2 auto-auth sections.  I've tried running 2 instances of Vault Agent, but get port-in-use errors.

Is there a way to use Vault Agent with 2 sets of approle credentials on the same server?  Is it better practice to create a new role with access to both backends?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, did you figure out how to do this? Facing a similar issue.

Comment: Some one told me to run two agents... I'm investigating this myself. (Actually turns out @Amit told me!)